# Selecting choice numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, random, integer

I have a list, `nums`, and I want to use the random module to pick an element from the list that isn't `0`.

So far, I have:

```
nums = [25, 0, 50, 0, 2, 45, 0]

for numbers in nums:
    for numbers != 0:
        s = random.choice(nums)
print(s)
```

But this doesn't seem to work. I expect `s` to be one of `[25, 50, 2, 45]` How can I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What is the exact question you want to pose? You may want to read [How to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following list-comprehension, which uses random.choice to pick from a list of all elements in nums which aren't equal to `0`.

```
>>> s = random.choice([n for n in nums if n != 0])
```

Answer (score 1):

because your value to be avoided is `0` you can also use `filter` build-in function with `bool`:

```
s = random.choice(list(filter(bool, nums)))
```

to avoid creating a new list you could use a while loop:

```
s = 0
while s == 0:
    s = random.choice(nums)
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution: create an empty list for the numbers different than 0. Iterate over `nums` and append to that list those numbers. Then, take a random choice.

```py
filtered_nums = []
for num in nums:
    if num != 0:
        filtered_nums.append(num)
s = random.choice(filtered_nums)
```

Slightly advanced solution: Make use of python's `filter` function.

```py
filtered_nums = list(filter(lambda x: x != 0, nums))
s = random.choice(filtered_nums)
```

Python's `filter` is very cool, very worth learning how to use it: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_filter.asp